# Scala error: class file is broken, bad constant pool index

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I'm trying to call the Selenium Java libraries from Scala. I'm using Scala IDE (Eclipse), and Scala 2.10.2. What is causing this compiler error?

```
error while loading Function, class file '/Dev/selenium-2.35.0/libs/guava-
14.0.jar(com/google/common/base/Function.class)' is broken 
(class java.lang.RuntimeException/bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 479)
```

Sometimes I fix broken class file errors by including more jars -- jars that `javac` would not need to see, but apparently `scalac` does. But is this case I don't know what other jars I can add.

Comment: Possibly related? https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7002

Comment: I just tried a couple other jar files -- no luck. Seems unlikely they were all compiled with Eclipse.  I'll see if I can get the source and manually compile though.

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer. It's caused by this: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1095. The error disappeared when I added the jsr305 jar.

Answer (score 4):

RobN's answer is correct, but I thought I'd write a little bit longer answer with my own experiences. This is related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20689122/1148030) and discussions on Guava issues [776](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=776) and [1095](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/detail?id=1095) mentioned by RobN.

I had this same problem trying to access

```
com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.base64()
```

Eclipse claims the base64 member does not exist and Gradle build
produces the error in the question:

```
[ant:scalac] error: error while loading BaseEncoding, class file 
   '.../guava-16.0.jar(com/google/common/io/BaseEncoding.class)' is broken
```

The error is caused by **optional** dependency on some annotations in [Guava's pom.xml](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/pom.xml#22). As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20698804/1148030), Java compiler ignores 
annotations for which corresponding class file is not found, but Scala compiler
requires the defitions to compile.

Explicitly adding the dependency that is optional should solve the problem.

In this particular case [Guava's pom.xml](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/pom.xml#22) has following optional dependency and adding the dependency declarations below to your project will solve the problem:

Gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.2'
```

Maven:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.google.code.findbugs</groupId>
<artifactId>jsr305</artifactId>
<version>2.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I think this is the same as my answer from 5 months ago, though the explanation about Scala is contained in the link.

Comment: @RobN Yes. I did quite a bit of googling to get here. I originally found the post in the link. After knowing the right keywords I searched SO again and found this question. I'm hoping that elaborating a little and crosslinking the questions future explorers will find results faster. I'm not sure if this is a good way to proceed on SO though...

Comment: In my equivalent case the initial error is: `error while loading GoogleService, class file '..../lib/gdata-core-1.0.jar(com/google/gdata/client/GoogleService.class)' is broken`. That [java package](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-java-client/source/checkout) depends on Guava. Somehow I fail to reproduce the solution with sbt using  `libraryDependencies += "com.google.code.findbugs" % "jsr305" % "2.0.2"` even though I already had that jar in my classpath (`/lib`) in the first place. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was a [known issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/12783) in `scala compiler` not handling method parameters attributes without names.

I just upgraded scala compiler from `2.13.10` to `2.13.11` and it fixed the compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it's a distinction between Java 8 and Java 11. The project is set to use Java 8, but the scala maven plugin uses Java 11. Setting the `JDK_HOME` environment variable along with `PATH` to point to java 8 worked in my case.

```
error: scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:
  bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 7817
     while compiling: <no file>
        during phase: globalPhase=<no phase>, enteringPhase=<some phase>
     library version: version 2.12.17
    compiler version: version 2.12.17
  reconstructed args: -bootclasspath ......jar -d output_path

  last tree to typer: EmptyTree
       tree position: <unknown>
            tree tpe: <notype>
              symbol: null
           call site: <none> in <none>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. my java was set 21.0 rather than java 8