# Cannot access a Java static method from Scala

Tags: java, scala, scala-java-interop

I'm having an issue with Scala and Java interoperability which Google and SO seem to be unhelpful (I've seen similar questions, but none offered a working solution for my case).

I have created a jar file in Java (hosted [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3119946/rowl-fetchers.jar), if you need it to answer this question) which contains a class with a static method. However, I can't seem to access this static method from Scala. Here's the code:

```scala
val graph1 = ...
val graph2 = ...
val union = DirectedGraph.merge(graph1, graph2)
```

The method exists, and I can access it with normal Java code. In fact, the following *works*:

```java
DirectedGraph<OWLClass> graph1 = ...;
DirectedGraph<OWLClass> graph2 = ...;
DirectedGraph<OWLClass> union = DirectedGraph.merge(graph1, graph2);
```

I've checked that the jar files being used by java and scala are the same. And I also checked to see if the method was indeed there with `javap`.

Is there an idea out there to understand and possibly solve this problem?

Comment: It throws two errors: `error while loading DirectedGraph, class file 'fetchers.jar(pt/remoteowl/objects/DirectedGraph.class)' is broken (class scala.MatchError/class DirectedGraph (of class scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$ClassSymbol))` and `value merge is not a member of object pt.remoteowl.objects.DirectedGraph`

Comment: It would be helpful to know what exact Scala version are you using, since “class file X is broken” have had various causes in different versions.

Comment: Scala version 2.10.1 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25)

Comment: The jar you provide is not self-contained; if I try to use it in the Scala repl I get "warning: Class pt.remoteowl.jar.Dependency not found - continuing with a stub". Are you sure that's not the root cause? I can't try to reproduce this on my own machine unless you provide all of the needed dependencies.

Comment: Hm... That may be the real problem! Thanks for noticing.

Comment: A ton of bugs got fixed between 2.10.1 and 2.10.3. If you're free to upgrade to 2.10.3, you should try it. (You might also try it in 2.11.0-M7, in case the problem has been fixed in the 2.11 series.)

Comment: The problem was indeed that a .class file was missing from the jar. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely reason (in my experience) is that the Java compiler treats annotations as optional, so that if one of your dependencies uses an annotation and there is no dependency which contains this annotation, it compiles without problems. However, the Scala compiler considers this an error. You may want look at `DirectedGraph` source along with its supertypes.

Comment: This explains way Java doesn't complain about the jar but Scala does. Thank you

Comment: Here is a related question and answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18600851/1148030