# Why am I getting "scala: error while loading AccessFlag" with IntelliJ CE?

Tags: scala, intellij-15

I'm getting the following error running Scala using IntelliJ CE:

scala: error while loading AccessFlag,
class file /modules/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessFlag.class is broken, reading aborted with class java.lang.RuntimeException
bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 5189

```
/* $Id$ */
package gov.uscourts.bnc

import java.nio.file.Files
import java.nio.file.Path

val usage = """
    Usage: encryptor ([-e] | [-d]) ([-in filename] | <arg>) > <filename> 
  """
def encrypt(string: String): String =
  Encryption.encrypt(string)

def decrypt(string: String): String =
  Encryption.decrypt(string)

@main
def encryptor(args: String*): Unit =
  if args.isEmpty || (args.length != 2 && args.length != 3) then
    println(usage)
    for (arg <- args) print(arg + " ")
    sys.exit(1)

  val e: Boolean = args(0) == "-e"
  val d: Boolean = args(0) == "-d"
  val in: String = if args(1) == "-in" then args(2) else ""
  val str: String = if args(1) != "-in" then args(1) else ""

  if e && str.nonEmpty then println(encrypt(str))
  else if e then println(encrypt(Files.readString(Path.of(in))))
  else if d && str.nonEmpty then println(decrypt(str))
  else if d then println(decrypt(Files.readString(Path.of(in))))
  else
    println(usage)
    sys.exit(1)

  sys.exit(0)
```

Here is my sbt output: (I'm using Scala 3.3.1.3 and Java 21)

```
[info] compiling 2 Scala sources and 1 Java source to /Users/satchwinston/IdeaProjects/encryption/target/scala-3.1.3/classes ...
[error] error while loading AccessFlag,
[error] class file /modules/java.base/java/lang/reflect/AccessFlag.class is broken, reading aborted with class java.lang.RuntimeException
[error] bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 5189
[error] error while loading ElementType,
[error] class file /modules/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.class is broken, reading aborted with class java.lang.RuntimeException
[error] bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 1220
[error] two errors found
[error] (Compile / compileIncremental) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 2 s, completed Jan 10, 2024, 4:34:18 AM
```

I ran it expecting it would run.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599804/scala-error-class-file-is-broken-bad-constant-pool-index