# logback 1.3.12, bad constant pool error with Scala

Tags: scala, logback

I have scala project with jdk 8 and I have logback dependency at version 1.3.9. It's working well but when I upgrade to logback 1.3.12, I get compiler error (MyClass.scala imports logback)

```bash
[error] scala.reflect.internal.FatalError:
[error]   bad constant pool index: 0 at pos: 13078
[error]      while compiling: /com/foo/MyClass.scala
[error]         during phase: globalPhase=typer, enteringPhase=namer
[error]      library version: version 2.13.10 
[error]     compiler version: version 2.13.10
```

I checked logback 1.3.12 dependencies and it supports jdk 8 which is the same as my sbt jdk.
I checked the logback docs but didn't find anything useful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scala error: class file is broken, bad constant pool index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18599804/scala-error-class-file-is-broken-bad-constant-pool-index)